# Upload file to S3 using powershell and windows task manager - credential error

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, taskmanager

I want to load few files to S3 on a daily basis, so:

I set AWS credentials using:

```
Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey XXX -SecretKey XXX -StoreAs SomeProfile
```

Then I use powershell script to load files to S3 using defined profile:

```
Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName SomeProfile
Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region eu-central-1
```

Result: When I manually run this PS script - everything is OK and files are uploaded. But when script is scheduled via Task manager... I get this error:

```
no credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults
```

Does Task manager use different settings ?

Comment: Did you configure the scheduled task with your user credentials as the logon account?

Comment: yes, I checked the name of loggon on user in a separate task - it is the same.